# VPNC and sudo access on Nitrous.io

Tags: nitrousio

I am thinking of using Nitrous for development, but I need at times to connect to resources that are on my network at work.  With sudo access ( I assume you have to pay for this ) can you install whatever you want on your box, like VPNC or Oracle Client Libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nitrous.IO doesn't provide sudo access as of Jan 2014.  We suggest that you add any packages you require to our autoparts package manager library:

https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts

If you need help writing a package, you can get in touch with the team by writing hello at nitrous dot io.

What types of packages are you looking for though?  We have package support for MySql, Postgres, Redis, Memcached, and many other services, languages and databases.

[EDIT APRIL 2015]

We just announced the next generation of Nitrous that supports root access on your own dedicated cloud VMs. Learn more here:

https://pro.nitrous.io

Comment: Was looking for the ability to add Oracle drivers.  A necessary evil dealing with "enterprisey" data sources.  Also vpnc.  These would enable me to entertain the idea of having developers use nitrous environments as a "standard".

Comment: I need to able to install these packages in order to run an android emulator for Meteor

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#libs32

I can't run the sudo command from the link as of last month (Jan. 2015 no more sudo for Nitrous.io according to the internet).

but your autoparts package manager doesn't have the packages I need from that link,

what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Sudo is not a featuire they offer.  Installing new applications is also limited.  They have an app called parts for managing packages, but the available list is quite limited.  You may be able to petition them for specific items, but otherwise you should probably be looking at a private server.

http://help.nitrous.io/autoparts/